# How to shorten the code in broom while running multiple regression in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, broom

I am running multiple regressions by different groups. I want to automate things a bit more. I tried to run and save the regressions model1, model2 and model3 initially. Then i tried to shorten the code as the following:

```
 temp <- df %>%
      group_by(group) %>%
      do(model1, model2, model3, data = .))) %>%   
      gather(model_name, model, -group) %>%                        
      unnest()
```

But this did not work. Below you find the long version that works. Can someone guide me on how to make it a bit shorter?

```
df <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(1000),
  b = rnorm(1000),
  c = rnorm(1000),
  d = rnorm(1000),
  group =sample.int(300,size=1000,replace=TRUE)-1)
)

df$group = as.factor(df$group)

temp1 <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(model2 = tidy(lm(a ~ b , data = .))) %>%   
  gather(model_name, model, -group) %>%                        
  unnest() 

temp2 <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(model2 = tidy(lm(a ~ c , data = .))) %>%   
  gather(model_name, model, -group) %>%                        
  unnest() 

temp3 <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(model3 = tidy(lm(a ~ d , data = .))) %>%   
  gather(model_name, model, -group) %>%                        
  unnest()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, using `nest_by` and `map` from `purrr`.

Instead of `group_by` try using `nest_by` (`dplyr` version 1.0.0) and run your model on each row of nested data. Using `nest_by` will create a new temporary list column `data`. It is similar to previously using `nest` and `rowwise`. The model needs to be in list as well here.

Using `map` you can conduct models for each independent variable "b", "c", and "d". Independent variable is also included as separate column (could also be a label for the particular model).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

df %>%
  nest_by(group) %>%
  mutate(model = list(map(c("b", "c", "d"), ~
                       cbind(independent = .x, 
                             tidy(lm(formula(paste0("a ~ ", .x)), data = data)))))) %>%
  summarise(bind_rows(model))
```

**Output**

```
   group independent term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <fct> <chr>       <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 0     b           (Intercept)   0.0480   NaN       NaN     NaN    
 2 0     b           b             0.268    NaN       NaN     NaN    
 3 0     c           (Intercept)  -0.124    NaN       NaN     NaN    
 4 0     c           c            -0.447    NaN       NaN     NaN    
 5 0     d           (Intercept)  -0.107    NaN       NaN     NaN    
 6 0     d           d             0.377    NaN       NaN     NaN    
 7 1     b           (Intercept)   0.473      0.296     1.60    0.356
 8 1     b           b             0.383      0.261     1.47    0.380
 9 1     c           (Intercept)   0.547      0.544     1.01    0.498
10 1     c           c            -0.183      0.798    -0.229   0.857
```

**Edit (12/19/20):** In case you want to include models with multiple covariates and interaction terms, you could simply provide the formula in the string.

For example, if you want to run 3 models per `group`:

- main effects "b" and "c" and interaction term "b*c"
- main effects "c" and "d"
- main effects "d"

You could do the following:

```
df %>%
  nest_by(group) %>%
  mutate(model = list(map(c("b + c + b*c", "c + d", "d"), ~
                       cbind(model = .x, 
                             tidy(lm(formula(paste0("a ~ ", .x)), data = data)))))) %>%
  summarise(bind_rows(model))
```

**Output**

```
   group model       term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
   <fct> <chr>       <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 0     b + c + b*c (Intercept)   0.718      0.281    2.56     0.0835
 2 0     b + c + b*c b             0.819      0.348    2.35     0.100 
 3 0     b + c + b*c c            -0.351      0.315   -1.11     0.346 
 4 0     b + c + b*c b:c           0.0444     0.461    0.0964   0.929 
 5 0     c + d       (Intercept)   0.614      0.409    1.50     0.208 
 6 0     c + d       c            -0.271      0.439   -0.618    0.570 
 7 0     c + d       d             0.182      0.487    0.374    0.727 
 8 0     d           (Intercept)   0.605      0.383    1.58     0.175 
 9 0     d           d             0.208      0.455    0.456    0.667 
10 1     b + c + b*c (Intercept)   0.590    NaN      NaN      NaN     
# … with 2,600 more rows
```

Or, if you want, you can list the equations completely and separately like this:

```
my_models <- c(
  "a ~ b + c + b*c", 
  "a ~ c + d", 
  "a ~ d"
)

df %>%
  nest_by(group) %>%
  mutate(model = list(map(my_models, ~
                       cbind(model = .x, 
                             tidy(lm(formula(.x), data = data)))))) %>%
  summarise(bind_rows(model))
```

**Output**

```
   group model           term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
   <fct> <chr>           <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 0     a ~ b + c + b*c (Intercept)   0.718      0.281    2.56     0.0835
 2 0     a ~ b + c + b*c b             0.819      0.348    2.35     0.100 
 3 0     a ~ b + c + b*c c            -0.351      0.315   -1.11     0.346 
 4 0     a ~ b + c + b*c b:c           0.0444     0.461    0.0964   0.929 
 5 0     a ~ c + d       (Intercept)   0.614      0.409    1.50     0.208 
 6 0     a ~ c + d       c            -0.271      0.439   -0.618    0.570 
 7 0     a ~ c + d       d             0.182      0.487    0.374    0.727 
 8 0     a ~ d           (Intercept)   0.605      0.383    1.58     0.175 
 9 0     a ~ d           d             0.208      0.455    0.456    0.667 
10 1     a ~ b + c + b*c (Intercept)   0.590    NaN      NaN      NaN     
# … with 2,600 more rows
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(1000),
  b = rnorm(1000),
  c = rnorm(1000),
  d = rnorm(1000),
  group =sample.int(300,size=1000,replace=TRUE)-1)
)

df$group = as.factor(df$group)
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the response. I was wondering how you can add an interaction in your code or multiple covariates. I tried to add "b"*"c" in list(map(c("b", "c", "d"). But then i got an error back.

Comment: @jad Please see edited answer. You can provide any equation you like for `lm` including interaction terms. Each string value provided should be either the RHS of a formula, or as in my last example you can provide the whole formula as a string. Please let me know if this addresses this adequately.